# How to apply Glossy effect to 3D Model?

Tags: swift, scenekit, metalkit

I want to apply glossy effect on 3D model, i am using SceneKit to load 3D model.
I have applied `metalness` and `roughness` properties but, it is looking something like below screenshot and `metalness` and `roughness` is not updating on rotation:

```
model.capsuleModel.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
model.capsuleModel.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.intensity = 0.5
model.capsuleModel.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.intensity = 0.5
```

[image: Applied metalness<code>and</code>roughness]

[I want something like this](https://clara.io/player/v2/02b9a872-185c-45ca-8827-b7e5fe22f60b?wait=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to add glossy effect using below code:

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
material.lightingModel = .phong
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.darkGray
material.specular.contents = UIColor.white
material.shininess = 0.1
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.childNodes.first?.geometry?.materials = [material]
```